# "unrecognized expression: [object Object]" when using $(..)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
 $(".budget-channel-table").each(function() {

        //get table
        var table = $(this);

        //create an array to hold the auto calculated widths of each element
        var thWidthsArr = [];
        var calcWidth = 0;
        $(table + " th").each(function() {
            calcWidth = $(this).css("width");
            thWidthsArr.push(calcWidth);
        });
 });
```

And I don't understand why I keep getting this error in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] th
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/). `table` is a jQuery object so when you use it in a string concatenation it creates selector like `[object Object] th` which is a invalid selector thus the error.

```
   table.find("th").each(function() {
        calcWidth = $(this).css("width");
        thWidthsArr.push(calcWidth);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
$(table + " th").each(function() {
```

With this:

```
$("th", this).each(function() {
```

Or use find method:

```
$(table).find('th').each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

`table` is a jquery object here is how you can use directly as a context to search into. Also you could simply use `this` if you don't need `table` later.

`$("th", table)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find()` to get the children of objects

```
$(table).find("th").each(function() {
    calcWidth = $(this).css("width");
    thWidthsArr.push(calcWidth);
});
```

Comment: @Neel Sorry i didnt get you?

Comment: nothing..by your surname Joshi it sounded like ur Guajarati so asked!

Comment: I'm from kerala bro. What about you?

Comment: im from Ahmedabad..are you Brahmin right? coz Joshi comes in my cast...I am Bhatt if you know this cast system

Comment: Nope. I'm a christian. Its a common christian name in kerala

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60878/discussion-between-anoop-joshi-and-neel).

Comment: sorry bro chat is not allowed in my company :/

Answer (score 1):

It's because table is already a jquery element. change it to this

table.find("th")......

```
$(".budget-channel-table").each(function() {

        //get table
        var table = $(this);

        //create an array to hold the auto calculated widths of each element
        var thWidthsArr = [];
        var calcWidth = 0;
        table.find("th").each(function() {
            calcWidth = $(this).css("width");
            thWidthsArr.push(calcWidth);
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in `.find` as shown below:

```
table.find("th").each(function() {
          calcWidth = $(this).css("width");
          thWidthsArr.push(calcWidth);
     });
```

For more information:
http://api.jquery.com/find/